# How do I make a key on the keyboard do *nothing*?

Tags: keyboard

My *right* control key on my keyboard sticks. I hit it accidentally often enough that I'd like to make it do absolutely nothing when it's hit. Is this possible?

Answer (score 12):

Use `xev` to find out what the keycode is. My `Control_R` is `105`. Then run this:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 105 = NoSymbol'
```

If that works, head into the start-up applications dialogue and add a new entry to run that command on boot.

Comment: If you put 'keycode 105 = NoSymbol' in ~/.xmodmap, your session manager should ask you to automatically apply it on next startup.

Comment: Oli - Thanks so much. The command works beautifully.

I did add a Startup with the command "xmodmap -e 'keycode 105 = NoSymbol'" but it didn't work for some reason. Any ideas?

Jacob - Will it hurt anything if I create ~/.xmodmap myself? I don't seem to have one already.