# How to block super powers?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have a <kbd>Super</kbd> or a <kbd>Windows</kbd> key on my keyboard. As a Windows user I'm used to using it to open the start-menu. On Ubuntu its a very sensitive key. Sometimes when I press it by mistake the whole system goes crazy (music stops, one time the whole system even froze) because it activates a pre-defined key-bind.

How can I turn off the additional powers of the <kbd>Super</kbd> key? When I press it I want it to do nothing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a key on the keyboard do \*nothing\*?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/43668/how-do-i-make-a-key-on-the-keyboard-do-nothing)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/105558/how-do-i-disable-the-super-key

Answer (score 4):

What you can try is to click on the power icon on the top right of the screen and select system settings.
[image]

You will have the following menu come up and you'll need to scroll down to the Hardware group if you need to.
[image]

Under the Hardware group click on the keyboard icon (although obvious I'm adding the photo for users who's systems aren't in English):

[image]

From here click on the Shortcuts tab as shown below:

[image]

Search through the types for those that use the <kbd>Super</kbd> (<kbd>Windows</kbd> on most systems) button and click on the shortcut and edit it as explained by the text underneath the window.  You can either make your own shortcut combination or just disable the shortcut. Hope this was helpful.