# How do I disable the page down (number 3) key?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

My keyboard has gone mad and keeps pressing the page down/number 3 key, it happens quite frequently. I have an idea of how I can disable it but when I try to get it's keycode it doesn't give me any input at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a key on the keyboard do \*nothing\*?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43668/how-do-i-make-a-key-on-the-keyboard-do-nothing)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

[How do I make a key on the keyboard do *nothing*?](https://askubuntu.com/q/43668/213052)

I found that when starting xev it was best to start it from a terminal/command line. It starts a separate window by default.
I guess this is used to capture the events. In my case the new window didn't give any feedback but there was output in the terminal where I started it and I could see the key press and release events there.

```
xev -event keyboard
```

My output looked like this:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x2c00001,
root 0x20a, subw 0x0, time 446757386, (133,520), root:(1097,558),
state 0x0, keycode 89 (keysym 0xff9b, KP_Next), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

You can then use xmodmap to set the key to do nothing.

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 89 = NoSymbol'
```